# Classical strings - Nat Geo "How Stars Are Born"

Tags: classical-music

A National Geographic video plays this classical music track in the background. Unsure if this "contemporary" music or not....

Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80eMTnnLjhs&t=1m13s

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like from the wonderful composer & cellist Phillip Sheppard https://soundcloud.com/radiomovies/across-the-milky-way for the documentary "Inside the Milky Way" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwSQVSlccCg

Here is another place that clarify it was him behind the contemporay music https://philipsheppard.bandcamp.com/track/across-the-milky-way "(This piece is a development of the title track of my score for 'Inside the Milky Way')"